# I cannot disable link on non-zero date

Tags: php, html, anchor, disable-link

```
    <tr bgcolor="<?php echo $rowColor ?>"  >
        <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f4; ?></font></td>
        <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f5; ?></font></td>
        <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td>
        <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $deliv_date; ?></font></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $i++;
        }
        mysql_close();

    ?>
    <tr bgcolor="<?php echo $rowColor ?>"  >
        <td>
            <strong>Total:</strong>
        </td>
        <td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td ><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f8; ?></font></td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <hr/>
    <div class="buttonwrapper">
        <a  class="boldbuttons" href="invoice_conf.php" <?php if ($deliv_date !=  '0000-00-00') echo 'disabled="disabled"' ?>><span>confirm delivery</span> </a>
    </div>
```

I am trying to disable the link in the last div when there is a non-zero delivery date. As you can see in the attached screen shot, I have a non-zero delivery date. When I try the link it is not disabled. Does anyone know why this could be,

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `disabled` attribute won't disable the link, if you want, just `echo` an `#` instead of the real source, or with Javascript, adding `javascript: void(0)`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YEs7A/2/)

```
<a class="boldbuttons" href="<?php echo ($deliv_date != '0000-00-00') ? 'invoice_conf.php' : 'javascript: void(0)'; ?>">
    <span>confirm delivery</span>
</a>
```

---

Or you can also use a `class` say `disabled_link` and if you want to prevent with pure CSS than use `pointer-events: none;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YEs7A/)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YEs7A/1/) *(Can also use lighter shades to indicate that the link is disabled)*

```
.disabled_link {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

---

Support for `pointer-events` is not impressive when it comes to Internet Explorer, I would suggest you to use `span` instead, like if the date *is not* `0000-00-00`, then `echo` the text in `span` tags, else `echo` `<a>`

Comment: That works, thanks. I wonder is it possible to hide the button altogether in the case of delivery date being present?

Comment: @Geoff Take the whole `a` tag inside an `if` condition :)

Answer (score 1):

add this after href.

onclick="return false;"

disabled is attribute for input tag.