# jQuery attach event only when anchor is not disabled

Tags: jquery, performance, events

i tried to attach and event and then check if anchor tag is disabled then don't do anything otherwise doSomething()

Here is what i have done so far and it results as expected;

```
<a href="#" disabled="true" class="btn btn-small btn-danger remove"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
```

Here is my jQuery;

```
acitivityListDataTable.find('tbody').on('click', 'tr td a.remove', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $this = $(this);
                if ($this.attr('disabled')) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    var link = $this.attr('href');
                    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?", function (result) {
                        if (result) {
                            window.location.href = link;
                            //milestoneTable.fnDraw();
                        }
                    });
                }

            });
```

However, i think its good (**or correct me if i'm wrong**) that i shouldn't even attach the event if the anchor tag is disabled;

So, here is what i tried but its not working and the click event is still working i.e attached.

```
acitivityListDataTable.find('tbody').on('click', 'tr td a.remove:not(:disabled)', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $this = $(this);
                    var link = $this.attr('href');
                    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?", function (result) {
                        if (result) {
                            window.location.href = link;
                        }
                    });

            });
```

**The difference is only here `tr td a.remove:not(:disabled)`**

**Update:**
i changed anchor to this;

```
<a href="#" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-small btn-danger remove"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
```

Comment: You cannot disable links using `disable="true"`

Comment: its working and disabled, the anchor is showing disabled in ui

Comment: `disabled="true"` is not a valid attribute for `<a>` tags

Comment: @DotNetDreamer You sure? http://jsfiddle.net/4ksfr/

Comment: yes i tried `disabled="disabled"` but still no luck

Comment: @DotNetDreamer Yesterday I answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22039837/i-cannot-disable-link-on-non-zero-date/22039949#22039949), just ignore php part

Comment: @Mr.Alien, the button is disabled, but i don't wanna attach the event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to prevent binding a click event to any `<a>` tag that has a "disabled" attribute (or, not selecting those elements)

I was able to achieve this here: http://jsfiddle.net/LL8yd/

The relevant code is:

`$('div').on('click', ':not(a[disabled])', function(){ /*..*/ });`

Answer (score 0):

@Jack is right, i adjust the code like following and it is working :)

```
acitivityListDataTable.find('tbody').on('click', 'tr td a.remove:not([disabled])', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $this = $(this);
                var link = $this.attr('href');
                bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?", function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        window.location.href = link;
                        //milestoneTable.fnDraw();
                    }
                });

        });
```